# Python Gmail API: No results returned when querying with multiple filters

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail's API for a Python 3 project. The project involves entering multiple filters to allow for the program to report when new emails matching multiple criteria come in. Here is a link to the reference I am using: http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.html.

The reference indicates that, in the `service.users().messages().list()` method, you can specify a parameter `q`, which is a query string that functions identically to the search bar in Gmail. (Meaning, you should be able to enter `from:sample@example.com is:unread`, and get back emails from *sample@example.com* that are unread. However, when I attempt to do this with emails that I have just sent to myself, I get 0 results back.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:sample@example.com is:unread').execute()
```

This returns 0 results, despite the fact that I can clearly see an email matching this exact criteria in my email, and when I attempt to use the search bar with the exact same query, the email is returned as it should be. I have attempted to do this with dates as well, and while it works with the Gmail search bar, it does not work with the API.

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:sample@example.com after:09/26/2020').execute()
```

There also doesn't appear to be an 'AND' operator, however, there is an 'OR' operator, which is not what I'm looking for. Has anybody else experienced this? And, if so, what is a way to fix this? I realize that this can be done without the Gmail API, but the purpose of this project is to use the API.

Edit: In case it helps, here is how the service object was defined, which is provided in the **quickstart.py** on their website.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']

def get_service():
    """
    Create a service object for Gmail api. (Gmail-defined code)
    """
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    print('Service successfully acquired')
    return service
```

The service object referenced in the snippets above was created by entering:

```
service = get_service()
```

Edit 2: I don't know if this sheds any light on this issue, but this query that I've tried returns results, whereas others with multiple parameters will return nothing.

```
message_list = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='in:inbox is:unread').execute()
```

Comment: The `q` parameter for Gmail aPI works exactly like from the UI. `from:sample@example.com is:unread` is a valid query. Test it with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) (make sure to not put the query string in quotes for this).

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I've tested the test UI (which works fine), but that's not what I'm trying to use - I'm trying to use their Python Client Library, which I linked in the first paragraph of the post - for whatever reason, the q-parameter (which should be a string, meaning that it needs to be in quotes) doesn't allow for multiple parameters to be passed, when the documentation claims that it should.

Comment: I am confused about the batch request method you linked. How did you define `service`?

Comment: Service was defined using the method in the **quickstart.py** that they have you run on the page. I'll add it to the original post if that helps.

Comment: I just tested the following request and it worked for me without issues: `    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:sample@example.com is:unread').execute()
    emails = results.get('messages', [])
    print('mails:')
    for email in emails:
        print(email['id'])` Are you sure you have messages that meet the query?

Comment: I do, I've typed the query into my search bar in gmail, and gotten the results that I'm looking for, and they're still marked unread. I really don't understand why it wouldn't return the results when I simple add a second parameter to the query, and it doesn't appear to matter what the second criteria is. It returns 0 messages.

Comment: For me it works perfectly with two criteria, but testing showed that if you implement empty space - e.g. `from:sample@example.com is :unread` or `from:sample@example.com is: unread` then the result will be empty - maybe this is your case?

Comment: Hmm, the only space that I've had was between parameters, not between the parameter and the value... Perhaps I should just try criteria other than my own email to myself. I just don't understand at all why it would be causing an issue.

Comment: I sent an email to myself from another one of my emails, and it's still marked as new in gmail - however, again, when I query for "from:sample@example.com is:unread", I get 0 results. But, when I remove the is:unread, I get 4 results, including the one that I just received, that hasn't been marked as read - I do not understand in the slightest what is going on.

Comment: Also, curiously enough, when I send a new message to myself, the number of results returned when I check for unread emails does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd just discovered what the issue is - I used `service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()`, And found that it showed the email that my chrome is connected to, rather than the one I was most recently logged in as. This is the entire problem. My apologies.

Comment: I am glad you found the reason!